# Multiple mysql joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables that I need get information from, 1 table has the information in and the other two hold information that i need to count.

so the first tables structure is:

```
tbl_img
img_id
img_name
```

```
tbl_comments
comment_id
img_id
comment
```

```
tbl_vote
vote_id
logo_id
```

I want the results to have the count of comments and votes that relate to each logo.

I have a bit of the query which is for the count of comments, but have no idea for the syntax for the second join.

```
SELECT l.img_id, l.img_name, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comment_count
FROM tbl_images as l
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_comments AS c USING (img_id);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this :

```
SELECT l.img_id, l.img_name, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_comments c WHERE i.img_id = c.img_id ) AS comment_count,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_vote v WHERE i.img_id = v.img_id ) AS vote_count
FROM tbl_images i
```

Comment: How come you dont have to do any joins?

Comment: the solution is using sub-queries and passing the outer images table i.img_id value through to the sub-query. We can do this only if the sub query return a single result

Comment: What type of value would the two sub queries return? A column name?

Comment: both numeric, the name is the bit after the AS . comment_count & vote_count.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need two queries for this: One for counting the votes, and one for counting the comments.

As far as I know, COUNT counts result rows, and joins create result rows to display all allowed permutations of joined tables.

Assuming you have I entries, each with J comments and K votes, you would receive J*K rows for each entry after joins, and COUNTs would both return that J*K instead of the correct amount.

I do not remember if you can do inner queries in MySQL, but that would be the way to go.
(See @Kevin Burtons answer)